# Cases in which $Pr(X|C) = 1$

Tags: probability

My conjecture is that there are only two cases in which $Pr(X|C) = 1$ (assume that $Pr(C) > 0$): if $Pr(X) = 1$ or if the probability of the intersection of $C$ and *NOT* $X$ is $0$. What do you think? Can you prove your answer? Does a theorem already exist somewhere?

Comment: Your conjecture fails for any $C$ with $0 < Pr(C) < 1$

Comment: Why? I don't get it.

Comment: For $X = C$ you have $Pr(X|C) = 1$ but $Pr(X) \not= 1$

Comment: Well, but this is a case in which the the probability of the intersection of  and NOT  is 0 (because the intersection of  and NOT  is 0); so my conjecture does not fail.

Comment: So you actually mean: $Pr(X|C) = 1 \iff Pr(X) = 1 \vee Pr(C\cap X^c)=0$?

But this is an "or" and not an "and"

Comment: Your reply is not readable; however, I should probably edit my question, because the case in which Pr(X) = 1 is just a special case of that in which the probability of the intersection of  and NOT  is 0.

Comment: Yes, mine is a "OR" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comments you actually meant: $$Pr(X|C) = 1 \iff Pr(C\cap X^c)=0$$

But this is pretty obvious:
$\Rightarrow$ follows by:
$$Pr(X|C) = 1 \iff Pr(X \cap C) = Pr(C)$$ as well as
$$Pr(C) = Pr(C \cap X^c) + Pr(C \cap X)$$
So in total we get:
$$  Pr(X \cap C) = Pr(C \cap X^c) + Pr(C \cap X)$$

Hence: $$Pr(C \cap X^C) = 0$$

The other direction can be seen by reading the proof upside down.